# Getting classCastException when running spark job on EMR cluster using Java 8

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-lambda, amazon-emr

I am writing spark job in spring boot application. When I am running my job in my local system it runs fine. But when working in AWS EMR cluster, it gives below exception

java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1.fun$1 of type org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function in instance of org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1

I checked the version of java which is 8 is same in local and emr, and same for Spark version which is 2.4.7

It gives error on below line

```
JavaRDD<String[]> lineRdd = javaSparkContext.textFile(linePath + "/*.gz").map((Function<String, String[]>)line -> line.split("\\^"));
```

Below is the stack trace:

```
WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, ip.ap-south-1.compute.internal, executor 4): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1.fun$1 of type org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function in instance of org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2301)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2437)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:503)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:461)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:83)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1405)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```